# LOGIC ON MySQL, DATE RANGES, inserting Items into null fields

Tags: mysql, logic, date

Ok so starting under select date range, I have a question regarding the logic on how this should come out.
I have to check that all members of my `enrollmenthistory` table are active for a certain month. The fields I have to deal with are `subclientcode`, `policyholderid` and `suffixid`

then I have enroll dates and disenroll dates
so my fields look like this

```
client phid sid enroll date disenroll date
```

the first thing I have to check is to make sure there are active members for that group (scc+phid+sid)

I want to break it down by month. so I would use `date_format(enroll_date '%Y %m)` to isolate the year and the date.

something like this maybe

```
SELECT sub client code, phid, sid, date_formate(enroll date '%Y %m'), 
date_formate(disenroll date '%Y %m')
FROM enrollmenthistory
WHERE sub client code = 'B01' and enroll_date is < 2010-02-01 and 
disenroll_date is null or disenroll_date > 2010-01-01
```

If someone could help with this syntax I use mySQL 5.5, and perhaps my logic is wrong too.

I have to take into consideration that there is an active member for one month but may not be active the next month, and may be active again the following month. Like insurance for union members.
Or the member may be active for only part of a month.

any help or questions to clarify would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

ALSO KEEP IN MIND

I have used this query before, but min and max wont work because of the specific date ranges I need to keep in mind.

```
SELECT  sub_client_cd, min( Enroll_date), max(Disenroll_Date), COUNT(*) as n 
FROM    big_pink.enrollment_test 
WHERE   Sub_Client_Cd = 'B01'  
AND     Policy_Holder_ID = 'BIS355702848' and Suffix_ID = 'e'
GROUP BY sub_client_cd;
```

This works but I need more specific...

And this is my latest code...

```
SELECT  sub_client_cd,  Enroll_date, Disenroll_Date, COUNT(*) as n 
FROM    big_pink.enrollment_test 
WHERE  Enroll_date < '2010-02-01' and  (Disenroll_date is null or  disenroll_date > '2010-01-01')
GROUP BY sub_client_cd;
```

How can I loop this using SQL, or would it be easier to throw it in a Python Script?